# Do you have a way to rewrite a class as a program is running (or change final values I guess)

Tags: java, class

Let me explain,
Theirs a plugin (video game mod) I want to make to add things to Another plugin (a different mod)  but I don't want to change anything in the plugin I'm not making.  But to add the stuff I want, I'd have to add some variables to some arrays in a certain class, which I could totally do form another class but Their finalized, and all the spots are taken.
SO after looking into how final variables work (i kinda guessed) I though it might just be easier to

make a copy of the class in question, put it in my plugin, change the variables so their not final, and... OVERRIDE the original class when the program starts... some how.

Ok not easy, but that was the only thing that came to mind, where I still didn't edit the original files, and my plugin could be removed and added without changing anything.

I've looked into Classloaders and something someone called a patching assistant (it implements ClassFileTransformer) but I have no idea what I'm doing.  SO I thought I'd post what I'm trying to do on here and see if anyone had any advice, I'll keep trying to figure out whether a class loader or patching assistant are viable for what I want in the mean time.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: change final values? final doesn't magically make a variable a constant. it depends on the variable declared as final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with reflection:

http://java-performance.info/updating-final-and-static-final-fields/

Although it's probably not such a great idea - these fields are final for a reason.

Comment: "final" and "constant" are not the same thing

Comment: OH! That totally worked! THANK YOU SO MUCH! (and thanks for the article, it was really easy to follow. THANK you thhank YOU thankyou thankyou!  I've been stuck on that for a long time. Dunno why I didn't ask earlier... THANKS! :D